# Calling synchronous code from asynchronous method

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I have read this question [Is this a proper way of calling synchronous methods asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623544/is-this-a-proper-way-of-calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously) which is similar to my question, but not quite the same.

I have a method

```
Private Sub SendEmail(strFromAddress As String, strFromName As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String, strToAddress As String, strAttachment As String)
```

that is used for sending e-mail messages from within my program. However, to avoid a slight delay to the user, I have created an asynchronous method

```
Public Sub AsyncSendEmail(state As Object)
```

which basically calls `SendEmail()`. I am invoking `AsyncSendEmail()` like so:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf AsyncSendEmail), params)
```

I am wondering if this is a correct way of passing off a synchronous method call into an asynchronous method so that it doesn't hold up the UI.

Comment: Working with UI imho [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx) is a solid solution

Comment: I see. I don't need the method to work with the UI necessarily, I just want to run it asynchronously so that it doesn't hold up the UI thread.

Comment: If you are using [`SmptClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and .NET 4.5+, then using the [`SendMailAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with `Async`/`Await` would be another option.

Comment: @Mark thanks, unfortunately I am stuck targeting .NET 4 for the time being because there are still a handful of users running XP... it is good to know that I will have that to look forward to once we can target .NET 4.5+ though!

Comment: Have you just tried your code if it is working? Nevertheless I would always prefer [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) over ThreadPool.

Comment: The code does work as expected, I was just wondering if this was the correct way to go about achieving this. I will look into using `Task` instead.