# Why does BackgroundWorker not need to call EndInvoke when it calls BeginInvoke on a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/532732/2697689) says that when you call the `BeginInvoke` method on a delegate, it is always necessary to call the `EndInvoke` method. Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620700/2697689) backs it up and suggests the class `BackgroundWorker` as an alternative.

I used ILSpy to decompile `BackgroundWorker` and I have found out that actually, `EndInvoke` is *never* called in this class, even though it does use `BeginInvoke` on a delegate.

Does this mean that `BackgroundWorkder` is ill-implemented, or is calling `EndInvoke` not so necessary after all?

(The issue with exceptions being lost is irrelevant, since the whole method being invoked is enclosed in a try-catch block)

On a similar matter: it there a clear reason why `BeginInvoke` was chosen in implementation of `BackgroundWorker` over say, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`?

Edit: the source code of `BackgroundWorker` can be viewed [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked for the man-behind-the-curtain for a while.  The CLR has secret knowledge of the SynchronizationContext class so technically it could be involved here.  Found absolutely nothing.

Until I checked what I should have done in the first place, actually verify the claim that EndInvoke() is required:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Action d = null;
        d = new Action(() => {
            d.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        });
        d();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Runs like gangbusters and consumes plenty of handles.  But it won't blow up, they never go over ~2000 and memory usage is completely stable.

So perhaps it is appropriate to tweak the claim that calling a delegate's EndInvoke() is required.  If you have a priori knowledge that the delegate target will not doing anything unusual, like calling into another AppDomain, running native code or activate remoted code then you can get away with not calling EndInvoke().  A guarantee that BackgroundWorker can provide.  I can never make that claim stick as just a mere SO user.  But Microsoft does it so it must be okay.  A comment in the source code would have been nice.

Comment: FWIW: I don't have a link handy, but I researched this question about a decade ago, and remember finding Microsoft-sanctioned references that described both the delegate and `Control`'s `EndInvoke()` methods as optional. I am surprised by the MSDN reference that apparently contradicts at least the delegate scenario reference I found earlier (but it seems that particular reference had that advice as far back as .NET 2.0). Of course, calling `EndInvoke()` is important if you actually want to receive the return value of the invoked delegate, so there's that. :)